# How to use Azure Runbooks to restart an Azure Web App on a schedule

Tags: azure-automation, azure-runbook

We have an Azure Web App that we want to setup an automatic restart on a schedule. If I wanted to use Runbooks for this, how would I add one or multiple apps to automatically restart on different schedules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to do this, and some will depend on the Azure-Runbook module versions you have.

1. You need to setup a user as 'RunAsConnection' user
2. To get a connection, you can use the cmdlet: **Get-AutomationConnection**
3. Then to add an authenticated account, you use: **Add-AzureRmAccount**
4. If you have multiple subscriptions, you will need to select the
   subscription to use: **Select-AzureRmSubscription**
5. Finally, use **Restart-AzureRmWebApp** to restart the web app.

If you set a `$result= Restart-AzureRmWebApp`, if the `$result` is null, then it didn't work, otherwise you will see the status of the running webapp. 
Eg. `$result.State = "Running"` if it worked successfully.

> To do this on a **schedule**: go to your Runbook > Schedules > Add
>   Schedule.
>
> Add the input parameters, and select/create a recurring schedule.
>   Click Ok and you're done!
>
> *** If you use a parameter for your webAppName, then you can reuse the
>   runbook, and just add different schedules with different input params

Sample Code.

```
try
{
    $servicePrincipalConnection= Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"

    # Logging in to Azure
    $account = Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "Azure subscription name"

    $result = Restart-AzureRmWebApp `
                -ResourceGroupName "Resource Name"
                -Name "Name of webapp you want to restart"

    if($result)
    {
        $state = $result.State
        Write-Output ("Web app restarted and is now $state")  #State should be Running at this point
    }
   else
   {
        Write-Output ("Web app did NOT restart")
   }
}
catch
{
    Write-Output ("Web app did NOT restart")
    throw $_.Exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because Az PowerShell modules now have all the capabilities of AzureRM
> PowerShell modules and more, we'll retire AzureRM PowerShell modules
> on 29 February 2024

Here is an updated example with Az PowerShell modules.

```
filter timestamp {"[$(Get-Date -Format G)]: $_"}       
Write-Output "Script started." | timestamp 

$resourceGroupName = "your group"
$appServiceName = "your app service"
$subscriptionName = "your subscription"
try
{
    $conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection" 
    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $conn.CertificateThumbprint | out-null

    # Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName subscriptionName

    $result = Restart-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $appServiceName

    if($result)
    {
        $state = $result.State
        Write-Output ("Web app restarted and is now $state")  #State should be Running at this point
    }
   else
   {
        Write-Output ("Web app did NOT restart")
   }
}
catch
{
    Write-Output ("Web app did NOT restart")
    throw $_.Exception
}
```